# Static Assets Cache with Spring

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am developing a web application and intend to make use of the performance boost that caching resources give, but it comes with an important caveat. Whenever I updated a static file, users wouldn't see these changes immediately, and so had to disable the browser's cache in order to fetch the newest version. In order to fix this issue, I decided to add static assets versioning. Which works as intended with the following code.

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
            .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(365, TimeUnit.DAYS))
            .resourceChain(true)
            .addResolver(new VersionResourceResolver().addContentVersionStrategy("/**"))
            // Costume made transformer to handle JS imports
            .addTransformer(new JsLinkResourceTransformer())
            .addTransformer(new CssLinkResourceTransformer());
}

@Bean
public ResourceUrlEncodingFilter resourceUrlEncodingFilter() {
    return new ResourceUrlEncodingFilter();
}
```

Everything was working as intended, except for one simple detail. JS imports were still loading the none versioned files. So something like `import * from './myscrypt.js'`, would not work properly.

I had to implement my own resource transformer in order to avoid that new caveat. The implementation does it's job, and now my imports would fetch the right version, like `import * from './myscript-149shdhgshs.js'`. Then, I thought everything was fixed, but a new issue came up. Here is the scenario, which will make it easier to understand.

1. I load a page that includes `script.js`
2. Then Spring serve me with the correct version of the file `script-v1.js`
3. After that, `script-v1.js` imports functions from `myscript.js`
4. The browser fetch the right version of the script `myscript-v1.js`
5. The two of them get cached locally
6. I update `myscript.js` making a new version `myscript-v2.js`
7. I reload the page, but since `script-v1.js` was stored in cache, I load it with the old import `myscript-v1.js`, even though there is a new version

I just can't seem to make it work. Of course, I could simply stop using `js modules` and instead just load all the scripts at once, but that is not the solution I want to go for. Would there be a solution for `js module` versioning using Spring?

Answer (score 5):

My way of solving this cached version will be using app version. If the project is built on Maven, I see you're using `classpath` resource for static file resolutions. Whenever there is a new change to js file, you will have new build and if you could change the version on every build, here is my workaround would look like.

**pom.xml**

```
<version>0.1.0</version>
<build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
</resources>
```

**application.yml**

```
build:
  version: @project.version@
```

This will push version from pom.xml to application.yml both dev on IDE and built jar

**Controller**

I'm using mustache view resolver here.

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @Value("${build.version}")
    private String version;

    private String encodedVersion;

    @PostConstruct
    public void setup() {
        encodedVersion = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(version.getBytes())).replace("=", "");
    }

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public ModelAndView home() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.setViewName("home.html");
        return mv;
    }

    @ModelAttribute("version")
    public String getVersion() {
        return encodedVersion;
    }

}
```

**home.html**

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/pop.js?cache={{version}}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.version = "{{version}}" // in case you need this somewhere
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Home1</h1>
  version: {{version}}
</body>
</html>
```

**Manipulating existing js files**

```
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureAfter(DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.class)
public class Config implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Value("${build.version}")
    private String version;

    private String encodedVersion;

    @PostConstruct
    public void setup() {
        encodedVersion = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(version.getBytes())).replace("=", "");
    }


    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/").setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(365, TimeUnit.DAYS)).resourceChain(true)
            .addResolver(new VersionResourceResolver().addContentVersionStrategy("/**"))
            .addTransformer(new ResourceTransformer() {
                @Override
                public Resource transform(HttpServletRequest request, Resource resource, ResourceTransformerChain transformerChain) throws IOException {
                    // Be aware of side effects changing line break
                    String result = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resource.getInputStream())).lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
                    result = result.replace("{{cacheVersion}}", encodedVersion);
                    return new TransformedResource(resource, result.getBytes());
                }
            });
    }

}
```

**pop.js**

```
import mod1 from './mod1.js?cache={{cacheVersion}}';
function dis() {
  console.log("hello")  
}
```

Since the version is added as `ModelAttribute` it will be available in all request mapping. For every version, this will be changed and the way you pull files can be using this cache version variable.

Comment: I like your approach, although, it can be prone to mistakes, since you will have to manually update the version of the project. Of course, it could be done with a randomly generated hash as `@Bean`, which would eliminate the need of manually set the value. Nonetheless, I haven't try it. Will let you know how it went.